# Why is my jar file refusing to distribute?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I have repetitively checked my manifest, libraries and project properties yet my simple runnable jar keeps present the error that the main class is unable to be found. I have attached a link to the source files and project folder, which includes the jar file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54ZddoX54HbcnZjQkY3ZXRBajg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems ok. What's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manifest file is case sensitive. It should be `MANIFEST.MF`

Confirm after your build that your jar contains that file with the Main-Class defined in it.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest.mf file you posted looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

In order to let java know what your main class is, you have to tell it. Like so:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.foo.bar.MainClass
```